# Adding collections/entities makes Form Rendering terrible slow

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm using the [Symfony2 Form Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) to make a form. All is working well, but the performance is terrible. A simple form (just a couple of text fields) is rendering in about 1000 ms, but with a entity or collection field it's slowing down to about 7500-10000 ms.

I'm using the `query_builder` (with `createQueryBuilder()`) option, like [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) from the documentation. Adding a [collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) or entity field makes the application terrible slow, but I don't know why.

[image: Profiler]
The Controller takes most of the time, so the Doctrine part (192 queries) or the Twig part doesn't seem to be the problem. Stripping the twig template doesn't help. I tried some improvements (caching) already, but that didn't help either.

How can I improve (or: see where's the problem exactly) the performance of this piece of code?

Comment: Please show your form code

Comment: Here's some code: https://gist.github.com/stephanvierkant/c78a8eade572a2b140ba

Comment: @forgottenbas Is that enough?

Comment: Are you testing in the `dev` environment ? ... probably having `xdebug` enabled? Using any opcode cache? Which PHP version? :)

Comment: @StephanVierkant How many records in your tables(each entity type)?

Comment: @nifr I'm in dev env, using APC, Xdebug and PHP acceleration. PHP-version 5.3.26, Symfony version 2.3.8.

Comment: @forgottenbas: About 20 records in Prices, 300 in Values.

Comment: @StephanVierkant what about `Lessor` and `ObjectType`?

Comment: Just a couple of entities. Removing the Values gives a performance boost of about 50%, so that's the show stopper.

Comment: Do you run your application on Windows or on Linux? On Windows I've a really bad performance up to 5-7 Seconds. On Linux I've 500ms. I Read that SF will do a lot of file exists and Windows hates that.

Comment: Use threads to collect the data and move it to a safe place, then use a thread in sync to push the data to Gui.

Comment: Did you found a solution for your problem? I supposed you disabled Xdebug profiling which decrease a lot the performance of Symfony2, it should be only activated when debugging and adds a 100% to 1000% of performance degradation depending on what is executed.

Comment: @createproblem I'm using CentOS.

Comment: @COil Not yet. Disabling xdebug gives a 50% performance boost, but rendering takes still about 4500 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your doing your form entity field and collection is bad and your performance issue may come from this.

First try to remove the queries you write in your forms, this is not the proper place especially with your queries which are the default one so no need to override them.

So you can do very simply like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        

    $builder
        ->add('ref', 'text')
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('lessor', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyCompany\AppBundle\Entity\Lessor',
            'property' => 'title')
        )
        ->add('type', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyCompany\AppBundle\Entity\ObjectType',
            'property' => 'title')
        )
        ->add('prices', 'collection', array(
            'type'      => new ObjectItemPriceType()
        ))
        ->add('values', 'collection', array(
            'type'      => new ObjectValueTextType()
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype' => true
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

Learn more about [entity form type here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage)

If you need to pass some choices like it seems you want to do, you will have to set the query_builder option and give it a repository method ([Example here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)), this is the correct way to do.

For the collection, you have a full example in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), I hope it will help you.

If it does not solve you problem, try to setup xhprof, it will give you a more detailed graph of your request and why it takes so much time : [Xhprof bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/jns/xhprof-bundle) 
[image: Example of Xhprof]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, changing the code doesn't help. Removing 'options' => array('data_class' => ....) brakes it: "The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess"

Choices vs Entity makes no difference in performance.

Comment: ok, could you upload your projet in a github repo so we'll be able to test it ? Thanks

Comment: I'm glad the community awarded you bonus points for this. IMHO, this kind of graph is an excellent example of [*how useless call-graphs are for performance tuning*](http://archive.today/9r927). The big red box is pointed at by not much of any explanatory value, plus it's all CPU time, no I/O time. The yellow boxes are the "hot path" leading nowhere, and the whole thing is embedded in a spaghetti nest of white boxes and arrows of no informational value. A single stackshot (or a few) will tell what the real problem is. Pardon my flame :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use data transformers http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more info about your template (twig files). 2 seconds on rendering looks suspicious.
And also check it again with disabled ANY profilers (e.g. xdebug).

If bad perfomance still exist (with disabled profiler) enable it and try to find slowest function and improve it, Xdebug could help you with it. I know it is huge, slow and ugly but it is the simplest way to do some measurements if you  didn't want to install any other

Comment: Thanks! Disabling xdebug gives a 50% performance boost, but the page is still loading in about 4500ms.